# Javascript to output different messages depending on answer

Tags: javascript

I am trying to have a simple postcode search where the user enters their postcode to see if they qualify for support. I would like it to be that once they have pushed enter it shows the result, at the moment I have it as keyup.

Due to it being postcode, it needs to search both with and with the space and also upper and lower case. Im hoping someone can help.

You can view the code here:
https://jsfiddle.net/esdrxq0n/3/

HTML

```
<h1>Enter your postcode to see if you qualify</h1>
<input type="text" id="postcode" value="" />
<div id="container" style="display:none;">Our services support your postcode</div>
<div id="sorry" style="display:none;">Sorry we do not operate in your area. Signup to be notified when we do.</div>
```

JAVA

```
$("#postcode").bind('keyup', function (e) {
    if (e.which >= 97 && e.which <= 122) {
        var newKey = e.which - 32;
        // I have tried setting those
        e.keyCode = newKey;
        e.charCode = newKey;
    }

    $("#postcode").val(($("#postcode").val()).toUpperCase());
});
var validcode = ('SS94QL','SS9 4QL','SS143JA','SS14 3JA');
    $("#postcode").keyup(function () {
        var code = $(this).val();
        if (code === validcode) {
            $("#container").show();
            $("#sorry").hide();
        } else {
            $("#container").hide();
            $("#sorry").show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,
Mainly you put the pre-defined codes inside an array,
 then you can transform the typed string to uppercase and see if it exists in the array

```js
$("#postcode").bind('keyup', function (e) {
    if (e.which >= 97 && e.which <= 122) {
        var newKey = e.which - 32;
        // I have tried setting those
        e.keyCode = newKey;
        e.charCode = newKey;
    }

    $("#postcode").val(($("#postcode").val()).toUpperCase());
});
var validcode = ['SS94QL','SS9 4QL','SS143JA','SS14 3JA'];
    $("#postcode").keyup(function () {
        var code = $(this).val().toUpperCase();
        if (validcode.indexOf(code) > -1 ) {
            $("#container").show();
            $("#sorry").hide();
        } else {
            $("#container").hide();
            $("#sorry").show();
        }
    });
```

```css
#postcode {
  width:50%;
  height:40px;
  background-color:#ffffff;
  margin:0px auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Enter your postcode to see if you qualify</h1>
<input type="text" id="postcode" value="" />
<div id="container" style="display:none;">Our services support your postcode</div>
<div id="sorry" style="display:none;">Sorry we do not operate in your area. Signup to be notified when we do.</div>
```

Comment: Thank you that works a treat! Are you able to do it on form submission rather than keyup?

Comment: yes you can do it to validate a certain form if you needs to.

Comment: At the moment though it uses .keyup to search after every key stroke, can it be done so that it displays the answer after the form has been submitted?

Comment: of course, as I told you can create your form submit button and put that snippet in the submit event.

Answer (score 0):

Your `validCode` should be an array and then you can use the `indexOf` function to find if the entered code exists in the array or not

```
var validcode = ['SS94QL','SS9 4QL','SS143JA','SS14 3JA'];
    $("#postcode").keyup(function () {
        var code = $(this).val();
        if (validcode.indexOf(code) > -1) {
            $("#container").show();
            $("#sorry").hide();
        } else {
            $("#container").hide();
            $("#sorry").show();
        }
    });
```

**[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/esdrxq0n/6/)**